# Weird behaviour of getchar regarding EOF

Tags: c

I'm writing a program that gets characters from the user using `getchar` and counts them. It's supposed to stop when the user enters EOF, print out the char count and print done. The code:

```
char cur = 0;
int count = 0;
while((cur = getchar()) != EOF){
    ++count;
}
printf("\n%d", count);
printf("\ndone\n");
```

However the loop doesn't stop until the user enters 2 consecutive EOF.
I tried to force the loop to stop by by manually checking if the char is EOF and breaking the loop but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I make it stop after just one EOF?

Comment: How does a user "enter" `EOF`?  It is not a key but a condition that is signaled in some fashion.  What keys did you press?

Comment: The `EOF` key typed (`Ctrl-D` on Linux, `Ctrl-Z` on Windows) must be the first character after a `newline`. Even then, I have not figured out why it sometimes needs more than one `EOF` from the keyboard.

Comment: I am using CTRL+D on Linux

Comment: @MichaelSapozhnikov I wonder then how  `(char)4` (a "control D") as keyboard input is entered?

Comment: `getchar` returns an `int`, not a `char` and either `EOF` or the full character codes cannot fit into a `char` (depends on its signed-ness).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getchar` function is declared to return an `int`, not a `char`.  Because you're assigning the result to a `char`, you won't be able to capture an EOF.

Change the datatype of `cur` to `int`.

EDIT:

This most likely has to do with how your terminal handles EOF.  When I tested this, if I enter one or more characters on a line and then press CTRL-D, the characters (minus the CTRL-D) are sent to the program and read by `getchar`.  If I press CTRL-D on a line by itself, even if I pressed ENTER to input the prior line, then EOF is detected.

If you were to redirect a file into the stdin of this program, you'd see that EOF is detected when the end of the file is reached.

Comment: So if the first EOF cannot be recognised from a char, then why is the second?

Comment: Thank you, woked like magic, but the question still interests me why does the 2nd time work but not the first?